# DllExportAppDomainIsolatedTask failed unexpectedly on building a DLL

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-task, unmanagedexports

I am trying to build the Dll in C# in Visual Studio. Used the NuGet RGiesecke.DllExport. However for some reason it returns some error when building the Dll. Bellow is the description.

> Error
>   The "DllExportAppDomainIsolatedTask" task failed unexpectedly.
>       System.ArgumentException: Requested value 'Version46' was not found.

Server stack trace:

```
   at System.Enum.EnumResult.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind failure, String failureMessageID, Object failureMessageFormatArgument)
   at System.Enum.TryParseEnum(Type enumType, String value, Boolean ignoreCase, EnumResult& parseResult)
   at System.Enum.Parse(Type enumType, String value, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at RGiesecke.DllExport.MSBuild.ExportTaskImplementation`1.<>c__DisplayClass8.<GetGetToolPathInternal>b__7(Version version, String toolName) in c:\Users\rober_000\Documents\Code\unmanaged-exports\RGiesecke.DllExport.MSBuild\ExportTaskImplementation.cs:line 568
   at RGiesecke.DllExport.MSBuild.ExportTaskImplementation`1.TryToGetToolDirForFxVersion(String toolFileName, Func`3 getToolPath, String& toolDirectory) in c:\Users\rober_000\Documents\Code\unmanaged-exports\RGiesecke.DllExport.MSBuild\ExportTaskImplementation.cs:line 725
   at RGiesecke.DllExport.MSBuild.ExportTaskImplementation`1.ValidateToolPath(String toolFileName, String currentValue, Func`3 getToolPath, String& foundPath) in c:\Users\rober_000\Documents\Code\unmanaged-exports\RGiesecke.DllExport.MSBuild\ExportTaskImplementation.cs:line 698
   at RGiesecke.DllExport.MSBuild.ExportTaskImplementation`1.ValidateFrameworkPath() in c:\Users\rober_000\Documents\Code\unmanaged-exports\RGiesecke.DllExport.MSBuild\ExportTaskImplementation.cs:line 680
   at RGiesecke.DllExport.MSBuild.ExportTaskImplementation`1.ValidateInputValues() in c:\Users\rober_000\Documents\Code\unmanaged-exports\RGiesecke.DllExport.MSBuild\ExportTaskImplementation.cs:line 396
   at RGiesecke.DllExport.MSBuild.ExportTaskImplementation`1.Execute() in c:\Users\rober_000\Documents\Code\unmanaged-exports\RGiesecke.DllExport.MSBuild\ExportTaskImplementation.cs:line 264
   at RGiesecke.DllExport.MSBuild.DllExportAppDomainIsolatedTask.Execute() in c:\Users\rober_000\Documents\Code\unmanaged-exports\RGiesecke.DllExport.MSBuild\DllExportAppDomainIsolatedTask.cs:line 241
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() NativeExports3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an issue about the `DllExport` package.

*Failing to compile in VS2017---Issue #29
        `Error The "DllExportAppDomainIsolatedTask" task failed unexpectedly. System.ArgumentException: Requested value 'Version46' was not found.`*

You can have a look at [this similar issue](https://github.com/3F/DllExport/issues/29), you should consume the [DllExport](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DllExport/1.5.2) nuget package for higner versions.(At least 1.5.2).

Comment: I installed Microsoft Build Tools 2015 and that solved my issue

Answer (score 13):

I installed Microsoft Build Tools 2015 and that solved my issue.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159

Comment: I'm using https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports got issue "Requested value 'Version47' was not found" in 2022 studio. Issue was fixed after installed this build tool 2015.

Comment: Got DllExportAppDomainIsolatedTask error. message "Version 46 not found" 
and using VS 2022. Issue fixed after installed this build tool 2015